# Grails doesn't put jquery library into HTML

Tags: jquery, grails

I've got this in my GSP in `<head>` section:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
```

but no effect in the resulting HTML - this is the problem to be solved.

jQuery plugin was installed by initial grails installation:

```
C:\...\qotd>grails install-plugin jquery
| Plugin 'jquery' with version '1.7.2' is already installed
```

And this code in GSP

```
<g:remoteLink action="ajaxRandom" update="quote">Next Quote</g:remoteLink>
```

results in html (calling jQuery.ajax method):

```
<a href="/qotd/quote/ajaxRandom" onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', url:'/qotd/quote/ajaxRandom',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#quote').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false;" action="ajaxRandom">Next Quote</a>
```

But of course no ajax methods are called and this link leads directly to another URL, because no jQuery is included in the `head` section. This is the problem.

Where did I go wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You need to add `<r:layoutResources/>` after your javascript library include.

Comment: Server Error 500 with message: Tag [layoutResources] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g

Comment: Did you used g:layoutResources? Use `r` instead.

Comment: Yes, I did by mistake. Fixed it and all works well now. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I also had to move the code from action's gsp to controller's gsp in `layout` directory

Comment: @Todd Murray - can you add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: If you are using grails3, the answer is in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813084/grails-3-0-gremotelink-ajax-call-replacement-due-to-deprecation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<r:layoutResources/>` after your javascript library include.